# how do I use this Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> as this ID3D11Device* (C++)

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, directx-11

The code I am using is C++ for DirectX 11 if this has some relevance.

I am using code that I have been taught to use. The thing is the class that calls my graphics methods has:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device>
```

This does not work with some of my methods though. They take:

```
 ID3D11Device*
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T>` to a `T*` pointer, use the **Get** method.

```
using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;

hr = D3D11CreateDevice( ..., device.GetAddressOf(), ... );
if (FAILED(hr))
   // error

...

SomeFunction(device.Get());
```

See [this wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class?view=msvc-170).

> Some older COM smart-pointers automatically converted to `T*` through an operator, but this is actually a problematic behavior which is why C++ Standard smart-pointers like `std::unique_ptr<>` use `get.()` for conversion to a raw pointer. For use of `->` or `[]`, the operator overloads take care of it. See [this article](https://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/) for more details.